# Issues reallocating memory to string

Tags: c, split, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

New to c and trying to learn.
Here I tried to create a function that copies a string until first space using dynamic memory allocation and byref.
Seems like I'm doing something wrong with the way I used realloc. Can you help me figure out what is wrong with the way I used dynamic memory allocation?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void f1(char **c, char *s);

int main() {
    char * s = "this is an example";
    char *c;

    c =(char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
    f1(&c,s);
    free(c);
}

void f1(char **c, char *s)
{
    int i=0;
    while ((s[i])!=' ')
    {
        (*c)[i]=s[i];
        i++;
        (*c)=(char *)realloc ((*c),sizeof(char)*i);
    }

    (*c)[i]='\0';
    printf("\n%s\n",*c);

}
```

Comment: My bad - I'll edit it. Still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: If your intent is only to copy a string (duplicate a string to another), then your code is way too complex and many things are done the wrong way.

Comment: @Sedenion Thanks. I'm new to c and trying to learn.
Mostly trying to understand why the realloc won't work.
Can you give me pointers?

Comment: @Niv first of all, do not call `realloc` each loop iteration. If you are dealing with null-terminating string, first determins the size of the string to copy, either using `strlen` or using your own implementation, then, allocate a new buffer of the proper size. Then you can simply copy values from one buffer to another until you encounter the null-char

Comment: @Sedenion yes - I will make it clear

Comment: @Sedenion thanks for the tip!  I understand why it would be more efficient.
Since the purpose is learning I'd very much like to understand given the code why it's not working.

Comment: Your code invokes *undefined behavior* because you always allocate one element too few in your `realloc` calls. Try Using `i + 1` in there

Comment: @SupportUkraine Thanks for the suggestion. If I allocate the memory in the function where would I free it if I need to use it in the main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void f1(char** r, char* s) 
{
   // find size of new buffer
   size_t len = 0;
   while(s[len] != '\0' && s[len] != ' ') len++;

   *r = (char*)malloc(len + 1);

    memcpy(*r, s, len);

    (*r)[len] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before the function call there was already allocated memory for one character

```
c =(char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

In the first iteration of the while loop

```
int i=0;
while ((s[i])!=' ')
{
    (*c)[i]=s[i];
    i++;
    (*c)=(char *)realloc ((*c),sizeof(char)*i);
}
```

this memory was filled

```
    (*c)[i]=s[i];
```

and then again there was allocated memory only for one character

```
    (*c)=(char *)realloc ((*c),sizeof(char)*i);
```

because in the first iteration of the loop `i` becomes equal to `1`. So in the second iteration of the loop there is an attempt to write outside the allocated memory that results in undefined behavior.

You need to write at least like

```
    *c = realloc ( *c, i + 1);
```

Also it will be more safer to use an intermediate pointer as for example

```
char *tmp = realloc ( *c, i + 1);
if ( tmp != NULL ) *c = tmp;
```

but in this case you will need also to change the function logic.

And the function should be declared like

```
int f1( char **c, const char *s);
```

and the condition of the should be changed like

```
while ( s[i] != '\0' && s[i] !=' ' )
```

Using your approach the program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int f1( char **s1, const char *s2 );

int main( void ) 
{
    const char *s = "this is an example";
    char *t = malloc( sizeof( char ) );

    if ( t != NULL )
    {
        t[0] = '\0';
        f1( &t, s);
        puts( t );
    }

    free( t );
}

int f1( char **s1, const char *s2 )
{
    int success = 1;

    for ( size_t i = 0; success && s2[i] != '\0' && !isblank( ( unsigned char )s2[i] ); i++ )
    {
        char *tmp = realloc( *s1, i + 2 );

        success = tmp != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            *s1 = tmp;
            ( *s1 )[i] = s2[i];
            ( *s1 )[i+1] = '\0';
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

The program output is

```
this
```

However such an approach with many memory reallocations is inefficient.

I would write the program the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * f1( const char *s, const char *delim );

int main( void ) 
{
    const char *s = "this is an example";
    char *t = f1( s, " \t" );

    if ( t != NULL )
    {
        puts( t );
    }

    free( t );
}

char * f1( const char *s, const char *delim )
{
    size_t n = strcspn( s, delim );

    char *result = malloc( n + 1 );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        result[n] = '\0';
        memcpy( result, s, n );
    }

    return result;
}
```

Again the program output is

```
this
```

Answer (score 0):

As @UnholySheep mentioned the `i` I used to allocate memory was too small.  Changed to `(*t) = (char *)realloc((*t),(i+1)*sizeof(char));` and it worked.